# JSONArray sort for listview - android

Tags: android, json, listview

"tipolistView.setAdapter(listViewArrayAdapter)Is it possible to sort a JsonArray by a key?

I mean, I have a listview , and it is being created this way:

```
{"id":"1","nome":"glamourhood","tipo":"1"},
{"id":"2","nome":"Face da Mia","tipo":"2"},
{"id":"5","nome":"Team Transformerz","tipo":"3"},
{"id":"6","nome":"Face da Team de novo","tipo":"4"},
{"id":"7","nome":"Tiago Faria Fitness","tipo":"5"},
{"id":"8","nome":"Nuno Soares","tipo":"6}
```

And I wanted it sorted by "tipo" from smaller to bigger, or even better : by type * id (that would be awesome).

Is this achievable on Android?

Comment: well, after it's in memory you can sort as you like.

Comment: Yes. It is achievable.

Comment: It is achieveable but i believe you will have to code the solution to actually sort it yourself. unless somebody already did this and posted the code somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deserialize your json into objects, like
(assumed these are movie titles)

```
@Serializable
public class Movie {
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("nome")
    private String name;
    private int tipo;

    public Movie();

    //getter & setter
}
```

For deserializing you could use GSON for instance. I've added an example for mapping json fields to different fields in an object (nome and name) when using GSON.

I can't come up with code for deserializing right now, but you will find plenty sources on the web. It must be somethiong like:

```
final Movie movie = gson.fromJson(yourJsonInputReader, Movie.class);
```

After deserializing those JSONs to objects, you may have a `List<Movie> movies`. Now you could sort this list in any way you want, use a `CustomCoparator` for this purpose.

```
public class MovieComparator implements Comparator<Movie>{
    public enum Field {
        ID, TIPO;
    }

    private Field field;

    public MovieComparator(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie mov1, Movie mov2) {
    int comparison = 0;
    switch(field) {
    case ID:
        comparison = mov1.getId().compareTo(mov2.getId());
    case TIPO:
        comparison = mov1.getTipo().compareTo(mov2.getTipo());
    }
    return comparison;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
Collections.sort(movies, new MovieComparator(MovieComparator.Field.ID));
```

Let me know if this works out or not, can't check it, because spending time with my son ;)